# wxPython - Automatically closing nested modal dialogs

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Python 2.7, WxPython 3.0.2

We are trying to automatically close an entire program under certain conditions. For various reasons, we can't just kill the process. We've had some level of success with it. We can close it if there's no modal dialogs, or a single modal dialog. Once we introduce the second modal dialog (nested), it fails to stop properly.

The actual error received appears to be:

```
wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "IsRunning()" failed at ..\..\src\common\evtloopcmn.cpp(83) in wxEventLoopBase::Exit(): Use ScheduleExit() on not running loop
```

Here's a working example of our issue. The frame will automatically close after 5 seconds. Clicking the button will load a dialog. Clicking the button on the dialog will open another dialog. It works fine until the last dialog is opened.

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import wx


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="TEST", size=(400, 400))
        self.Show()
        self.__someDialog = None
        self.__myThread = None

        self.__okButton = wx.Button(self, -1, "Press me")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.__onOK)

        self.__myThread = Thread(target=self.__waitThenClose, name="Closer")
        self.__myThread.setDaemon(True)
        self.__myThread.start()

    def __onOK(self, evt):
        self.__someDialog = SomeDialog(self)
        self.__someDialog.ShowModal()

    def closeOpenDialogs(self):
        lst = wx.GetTopLevelWindows()

        for i in range(len(lst) - 1, 0, -1):
            if isinstance(lst[i], wx.Dialog):
                print "Closing " + str(lst[i])
                lst[i].Close(True)
                #lst[i].Destroy()

    def __waitThenClose(self):

        for x in range(0, 5):
            print "Sleeping..."
            sleep(1)

        self.closeOpenDialogs()
        wx.CallAfter(self.Close, True)


class SomeDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, id=-1, title='Some Dialog')
        self.SetSize((300, 300))
        self.__anotherDialog = None
        self.__okButton = wx.Button(self, -1, "Press me")

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.__onOK)
        wx.EVT_CLOSE(self, self.__on_btn_cancel)

    def __onOK(self, evt):
        self.__anotherDialog = AnotherDialog(self)
        self.__anotherDialog.ShowModal()

    def __on_btn_cancel(self, event):
        self.EndModal(wx.ID_CANCEL)


class AnotherDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, None, id=-1, title='Another Dialog')
        self.SetSize((200, 200))
        wx.EVT_CLOSE(self, self.__on_btn_cancel)

    def __on_btn_cancel(self, event):
        self.EndModal(wx.ID_CANCEL)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = wx.App()

    mainFrame = MainFrame()

    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: i didnt run it ... but try overriding `self.Close`, and  moving `self.closeOpenDialogs()` into your new Close method ... my guess is you are calling `self.closeOpenDialogs` from inside your thread ...and you should never update gui from inside a thread ... really if the parent is destroyed it should destroy all the children

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what is happening here is that the first call to `ShowModal()` blocks the at the app level (not just the frame level) which is preventing the second dialog from becoming fully initialized. To work around this issue I would call `Show()` instead of `ShowModal()` and add `wx.FRAME_FLOAT_ON_PARENT` to the dialog style flags. You can also call `Disable()` on the parts of the program you don't want the user to interact with while the dialogs are open.

EDIT: Here is a working example:

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import wx


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="TEST", size=(400, 400))
        self.Show()
        self.__someDialog = None
        self.__okButton = wx.Button(self, -1, "Press me")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.__onOK)

        self.__myThread = Thread(target=self.__waitThenClose, name="Closer")
        self.__myThread.setDaemon(True)
        self.__myThread.start()

    def __onOK(self, evt):
        self.__someDialog = SomeDialog(self)
        self.__someDialog.ShowModal()

    def closeOpenDialogs(self, evt=None):
        lst = wx.GetTopLevelWindows()
        for i in range(len(lst) - 1, 0, -1):
            dialog = lst[i]
            if isinstance(dialog, wx.Dialog):
                print "Closing " + str(dialog)
                # dialog.Close(True)
                wx.CallAfter(dialog.Close)
                # sleep(1)
                # dialog.Destroy()

    def __waitThenClose(self):
        for x in range(0, 10):
            print "Sleeping..."
            sleep(1)
        wx.CallAfter(self.closeOpenDialogs)
        wx.CallAfter(self.Close, True)


class SomeDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, id=-1, title='Some Dialog')
        self.SetSize((300, 300))
        self.__anotherDialog = None
        self.__okButton = wx.Button(self, -1, "Press me")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.__onOK)
        wx.EVT_CLOSE(self, self.__on_btn_cancel)

    def __onOK(self, evt):
        self.__anotherDialog = AnotherDialog(self)
        self.__anotherDialog.SetWindowStyleFlag(
            wx.FRAME_FLOAT_ON_PARENT|wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE)
        self.__anotherDialog.Show()

    def __on_btn_cancel(self, event):
        event.Skip()
        self.EndModal(wx.ID_CANCEL)


class AnotherDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, id=-1, title='Another Dialog')
        self.SetSize((200, 200))
        wx.EVT_CLOSE(self, self.__on_btn_cancel)
        parent.Disable()

    def __on_btn_cancel(self, event):
        event.Skip()
        self.GetParent().Enable()
        # self.EndModal(wx.ID_CANCEL)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    mainFrame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: This works well :) using `Show` instead of `ShowModal` is a nice trick

Answer (score 0):

The only way to reliably gracefully close all the modal dialogs, whether they were explicitly opened by your own code or not, is to use [wxModalDialogHook](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0.2/classwx_modal_dialog_hook.html) to remember all the opened dialogs and then close them all, in the reverse (i.e. LIFO) order, before quitting the application.

Unfortunately I don't know if `wxModalDialogHook` is available in Python.